# Number of prime factors in a very short interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $k \geq 3$ be a (large enough) integer, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, 
>   and set $I_x := [x, x + \log^k x]$.

Some believe that for $x$ large enough there exists a prime $n \in I_x$.
Equivalently, there exists (for large enough $x$) an $n \in I_x$ with $\omega(n) = 1$ where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. This seems to be out of reach for the moment.

> What (upper) bound can be proved (even assuming big conjetures like
>   GRH or ABC) on $$\min \ \{\omega(n) \ | \ n \in I_x \}$$ for large
>   enough values of $x$?

The (very weak) bound that I managed to obtain is: $C(k)\frac{\log x}{\log \log x}$ where $C(k)$ is approximately (an absolute constant times) $1/k$.
This improves upon the trivial upper bound $O(\frac{\log x}{\log \log x})$. I am therefore eager to know if a bound of the form $o(\frac{\log x}{\log \log x})$ can be established.

For (substantially) longer intervals, the Erdos-Kac theorem holds, so much better bounds are available.

> I am not interested in results about almost all values of $x$, or
>   about averaging over $x$.

Comment: What prevents you from proving results like log log x for the minimum?  I assume the width of the interval is $(\log x)^k $ which is greater than $2^k$? There can't be that many occurrences of small prime factors, can there? Gerhard "Is Also Interested In This" Paseman, 2017.07.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I took into account the occurences of small primes, and from that I could not arrive at $\log\log x$ but only at that weak bound mentioned in the question.

Comment: I wanted to mention: For almost all $x$, that is all but $o(X)$ of the integers $x\leq X$, and $k>5$, we can unconditionally show that $$\min\left\{\omega(n)| n\in I_x\right\}\leq 2.$$ (See Mikawa's paper "Almost-primes in arithmetic progressions and short intervals.")

Comment: Perhaps one would need first to establish a lower bound for the quantity  $ \Delta_{k,\omega}(x) : =\sup_{n,m\in I_{x}}\vert \omega(n)-\omega(m)\vert $ .

Comment: Also, one should have  $ \sum_{n\in I_{x}}n^{-\omega(n)}=\sum_{p\in I_{x}}p^{-1}+O(1) $  for almost trivial reasons. I don't know how to evaluate the first sum though. And of course the  $ O(1) $ is really crude and comes from the formula  $ \sum_{m>1}(\zeta(m)-1)=1 $ .

Comment: MathOverflow user Joni Teravainen (apologies for poor typesetting and no umlauts) cites the Mikawa paper and says that he can almost always find bounds of 2 when the exponent on log is 3.51, and of 3 for exponent 1+ epsilon.  He has an ArXiv print from 2015 on this (1510.06005). Not quite what the poster wants though.  Gerhard "Is Making A Gender Presumption" Paseman, 2017.07.11

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The poster is quite clear about what he wants in the question.

"I am not interested in results about almost all values of $x$"

Comment: Which is why your comment surprised me Eric.  However, it may be the same exponent will work for him. Do you know how to extend Mikawa's (or others) work from almost all x to all x? Gerhard "Occasionally Wonders About Others Comments" Paseman, 2017.07.12.

Comment: The scenario that needs eliminating is when every number in $[x, x+\log^k x]$ is the product of about $\frac{1}{100k} \frac{\log x}{\log\log x}$ primes of size comparable to $\log^{100 k} x$, times some smaller primes (up to $\log^k x$ in size, but a typical number in the interval would only have about $O(k \log\log x)$ such factors), with none of these medium sized primes being used more than once.  I don't know of any technique (even assuming ABC etc.) that would eliminate this scenario.